# How can configure IIS to service to AD users only?

Tags: active-directory, iis

I have an intranet in my company and I have a domain controller that users authenticate with this,I have an internal web site (IIS) I want limit this site that services only to my domain users.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Under Authentication in IIS, disable Anonymous Authentication, Enable Windows Authentication.

If you do not see Windows Authentication, you need to add that Role Service for IIS.

This will prompt anyone going there for log and password, which will authenticate against the AD.